# How to send field "widget" as file and as field?

Tags: php, curl

How to send field "widget" as file and as field to get `$_POST['widget']` equal "my_widget" and get `$_FILES['widget']`

send.php

```
$fields = [
    'widget'=> new CURLFile('widget.zip','','widget'),
        'widget'=>'my_widget'
    'secret'=>$res['secret_key'],
    'amouser'=>$user['email'],
    'amohash'=>$user['key']
];

echo json_encode($fields);

$link = 'http://example.ru/test_get.php';
$curl=curl_init(); #Сохраняем дескриптор сеанса cURL
#Устанавливаем необходимые опции для сеанса cURL
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $delimiter,
//'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields)));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);

$out=curl_exec($curl); #Инициируем запрос к API и сохраняем ответ в переменную
$code=curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$code=(int)$code;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $out;
```

test_get.php

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: I can't control test_get.php This receiver require `$_POST['widget'] = 'my_widget'` and `$_FILES['widget']`

Comment: Try setting a single `widget` key with an array value, eg `'widget' => [new CURLFile('widget.zip', '', 'widget'), 'my_widget']`